# Validate a record before against the records in another Object before saving - Salesforce

Tags: validation, configuration, salesforce, apex

I have a requirement where in Opportunity record detail page has Customer, Agency, Sales Owner, Account Manager fields and there is another custom object name Data combine that stores the data of all the records with all the possible combinations that is allowed in the above mention fields of Opportunity.

When the user populates Customer, Agency, Sales Owner and Account Manager fields in Opportunity and click on Save, the data in these fields should be validated against the records in the custom object. And if the combination of all these fields doesn't match with any of the rows in the custom Object, then the record should not be saved and an error message should be thrown or displayed.

Can someone please let me know if this scenario can be implemented in Salesforce using configuration or Apex? if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure config way:

1. /Are you sure it has to use a helper object? Have you considered dependent picklists or lookup filters (if some of these are lookups) and well, if user enters invalid combination but all fields are required - they won't be able to save?
2. Assuming it can't be dependent picklists: If you set the `Data_combine__c.Name` to be a text field (not autonumber) and populate it (using workflow?) with the values from these fields. So if Customer = "Acme Ltd", Agency = "New York office", Sales Owner = "John Doe", Account Manager = "Joe Bloggs" then the Name would be "Acme Ltd;New York Office;John Doe;Joe Bloggs"

Then you should be able to use [`VLOOKUP`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5) function in a validation rule. There are lots of blog posts and Youtube videos with examples. The obvious problem here is that it must be comparison against `Name` field which will be limited to 80 characters. If you have long company names that won't work well.

3. So worst case you could code it as `before insert, before update` trigger on Opportunity. Collect all field values from `trigger.new`, run a query against the Data Combine, maybe build a helper `Map<String, Data_Combine__c>` where key would be structure similar to the `Name` idea (but without the 80 chars limit) and compare?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I guess I should go for the third one because of the name field limitation. I'll try that.

Comment: Edit your question and @mention me or make new one if you get stuck?

Comment: Sure. Thank you.